# Why is the formatting/syntax for assert_equal hashes different than other assert_equals?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I'm working my way through the [Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com/) and am currently on AboutHashes.  Up to this point the assert_equals have followed a specific formatting style of: `assert_equal` space `expected_value` comma `actual value` (e.g., `assert_equal 2, 1 + 1`).  But the test_creating_hashes def in About Hashes has an assert_equal that doesn't follow this pattern, and if I change it to match that pattern it fails.  Specifically:

```
def test_creating_hashes
  empty_hash = Hash.new
  assert_equal {}, empty_hash  # --> fails 
  assert_equal({}, empty_hash) # --> passes  
end
```

So what's special about the `assert_equal` in this situation?

The meat of the test failure message is:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require':    /Ruby_on_Rails/koans/about_hashes.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
assert_equal {}, empty_hash #{} are also used for blocks
                ^
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from path_to_enlightenment.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Interesting edge case, but it'd probably be easier to answer if you gave the test failure message.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It fails because Ruby parses the first example as passing in an empty block {}, not an empty hash. I wouldn't be surpised if it gave a SyntaxError (see below).

However by explicitly putting the parenthesis, you are telling ruby "these are the arguments I want to pass into this method".

```
def t(arg1, arg2)
  p arg1
end


ruby-1.9.2-p136 :057 > t {}
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :056 > t {}, arg2
SyntaxError: (irb):56: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting $end
t {}, arg2
```

Comment: `assert_equal ({}), empty_hash` also worked.  I'm assuming this means the parser interprets `({})` as an empty hash?